# Implementing a work queue in postresql

Tags: postgresql, rowlocking

I want to make a persistent job queue in postgresql. So that multiple workers can select one job from the queue (using `select for update` with `skip locked`), process it and than delete it from the queue. I have a table:

```
create table queue (
   id serial primary key
   some_job_param1 text not null
   some_job_param2 text not null
)
```

Now if there are two jobs then it works fine:

the `worker1` starts a transaction and selects the first job

```
begin;
select * from queue for update skip locked limit 1;
```

starts the processing. `worker2` does the same thing and selects the second job with the same query.

After `worker1` does it's job, deletes it from the queue and commits the transaction:

```
delete from queue where id=$1;
commit;
```

Then the `worker1` is ready for a new job, so it does the same thing. Begins a new transaction, selects for a job that isn't locked. But the problem is, that there are no more jobs, the query returns zero rows.

Ideal would be if the query would block until there is a new job and it returns a result. Is it somehow possible? Or I'm going in a wrong direction?

**EDIT:**

the workers are an external process. So if the worker died, the session dies and the transaction also. Then the selected job will be locked no more and ready for another worker. The pseudo code would look like this:

```
while (true) {
  tx = db.new_transaction()
  job_id, param1, param2 = tx.query("select * from queue for update skip locked limit 1")
  try {
    some_long_processing(param1, param2)
    tx.commit()
  } catch {
    tx.rollback()
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are going in the wrong direction. Have the worker sleep for a while before it next looks for work to do.

Comment: Is our "work queue" program purely PG code or some external program in other lang? How do you assure worker did not died away?

Comment: I've edited the question. The workers are a separate process in other lang and will run on another machine. They just need to collect the parameters for the job. The best would be if they didn't periodically just select the database for an empty queue, but get the response to start the job immediately